# New Android device doesn't show up in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I bought a new Android device. It's a Nokia 7 Plus and it has the current OS version 9.

I connected the device with a USB cable to my Mac but the device doesn't show up in Visual Studio for Mac.

Why is the device not showing up in VS for Mac?

Visual Studio for Mac picture:
[image]

Comment: Need to active developer mode in device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Enable Developer Options](https://droidusb.com/download-usb/enable-usb-debugging-in-nokia-7-plus/) on the device.
2. Go to the now-enabled Developer Options menu item, and tap on USB Debugging option to enable it.